# \n\t Characters are visible inside label on MFC CDialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a text with `\t` characters. And when I open the dialog I see this characters and they are not affect on the text . What is the reason ?
So for example i need the following format:

```
Result:   1. Some text.
          2. Some text.
```

And I created a string `Result:   \t1. Some text.\n\t2. Some text.`

And as a result I got "Result:   \t1. Some text.\n\t2. Some text" in the label. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _"The recommended method for displaying text with specified line breaks is to use multiple one-line text controls located below each other. The character sequences \n, \r\n, or \n\r in the text field for the control are not displayed as a line break. These character sequences are literally displayed by the control."_ source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372076(v=vs.85).aspx  You might want to investigate the Rich Edit Control which can do limited formatting.

Comment: Please show us your code. I can't believe that an edit or static control shows a tab in this form.

Comment: I found solution .In my case this string was in the lan file. And I have no need to use formatting characters . Thanks